# Text wrap in TextView within a Tab

Tags: android, xml

[image]

First off, sorry about the large screen. I am trying to get the text to wrap but am currently unable to do so. I have tried android:layout_width="fill_parent", android:scrollHorizontal="false", android:width="0dip" all of which suggested in another question. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve text wrapping? Here's a sample of the xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:stretchColumns="2">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/lgrayborder"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/chatUser1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/lgrayborder"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/chatComm1"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/lgrayborder"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/chatUser2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/lgrayborder"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/chatComm2"/>

    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Update: I have tried setting attributes in the ScrollView, TableLayout, and TableRow in hopes that it would force the TextViews to wrap but to no avail. Still looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tried to use

```
android:maxEms="int"
```

in combination with ellipsize? This should solve your problems.

Comment: You sir, are a <*explicit*> genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with TableLayout and fixed it by setting column shrinkable to "true" like this:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById( R.id.ViewTaskTable );
tl.setColumnShrinkable( 0, true );
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) property of the [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Comment: I tried these three android:ellipsize="start", android:singleLine="false", android:scrollHorizontally="false", and none of them worked. Also, Ellipsize is so that words don't get broken in the middle, useful but does not really solve the main issue.

Comment: Try singleLine="true" and ellipsize="end". HTH !